# Noob PHP form logic questions

Tags: php

I was given a bunch of code (PHP) which was not documented very well; that said, I have some form logic that doesn't make any sense to me.  Here is the page html code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
if ($itemcount == 0)
    {
        header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("Please add items to your shopping cart before checking out."));
        exit;
    } 

if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("We did not find your information, please fill the needed information again."));
        exit;
    } 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $_SESSION['shipname'] = $_POST['shipname'];
        $_SESSION['shipaddress'] = $_POST['shipaddress'];
        $_SESSION['shipzip'] = $_POST['shipzip'];
        $_SESSION['shipcity'] = $_POST['shipcity'];
        $_SESSION['shipstate'] = $_POST['shipstate'];
        $_SESSION['shipcountry'] = $_POST['shipcountry'];

        $_SESSION['paymenttype'] = $_POST['paymenttype'];
        $_SESSION['cardname'] = $_POST['cardname'];
        $_SESSION['cardno'] = $_POST['cardno'];
        $_SESSION['cardmonth'] = $_POST['cardmonth'];
        $_SESSION['cardyear'] = $_POST['cardyear'];

        header("Location: "."thankyou.php");
    } 

$shipname = isset($_SESSION['shipname']) ? $_SESSION['shipname'] : '';
$shipaddress = isset($_SESSION['shipaddress']) ?    $_SESSION['shipaddress'] : '';
$shipzip = isset($_SESSION['shipzip']) ? $_SESSION['shipzip'] : '';
$shipcity = isset($_SESSION['shipcity']) ? $_SESSION['shipcity'] : '';
$shipstate = isset($_SESSION['shipstate']) ? $_SESSION['shipstate'] : '';
$shipcountry = isset($_SESSION['shipcountry']) ? $_SESSION['shipcountry'] : '';
$cardname = isset($_SESSION['cardname']) ? $_SESSION['cardname'] : '';
$cardno = isset($_SESSION['cardno']) ? $_SESSION['cardno'] : '';

?>
```

Here is the form html:

```
<div id="wb_checkout" style="position:absolute;width:957px; height:374px;">
  <form name="checkout" method="post" action="checkout.php" id="checkout">
    <div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:32px;top:88px;width:88px;height:34px;z-index:36;">
      <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;">
        <div><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:16px;">Address:  </span>    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:32px;top:138px;width:61px;height:34px;z-index:37;">
      <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;">
        <div><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:16px;">City:</span>    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wb_Text6" style="position:absolute;left:32px;top:193px;width:88px;height:42px;z-index:38;">
      <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;">
        <div><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:16px;">Zip Code:</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wb_Text7" style="position:absolute;left:294px;top:195px;width:74px;height:34px;z-index:39;">
      <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;">
        <div><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:16px;">State:</span>    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:32px;top:37px;width:88px;height:34px;z-index:40;">
      <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;">
        <div><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:16px;">Name:</span>    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:125px;top:85px;width:412px;height:34px;line-height:34px;z-index:41;" name="shipaddress" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;left:99px;top:137px;width:412px;height:34px;line-height:34px;z-index:42;" name="shipcity" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox4" style="position:absolute;left:373px;top:195px;width:65px;height:34px;line-height:34px;z-index:43;" name="shipstate" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:124px;top:36px;width:412px;height:34px;line-height:34px;z-index:44;" name="shipname" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox5" style="position:absolute;left:125px;top:194px;width:117px;height:34px;line-height:34px;z-index:45;" name="shipzip" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="submitOrder" value="Submit Order" style="position:absolute;left:612px;top:317px;width:110px;height:36px;z-index:46;">
    <input type="submit" id="Button2" name="cancelOrder" value="Cancel Order" style="position:absolute;left:761px;top:318px;width:114px;height:35px;z-index:47;">
  </form>
</div>
```

This is an image of the form:
[image]

The problem is that this page is not being rendered; it just skips to the next page (thankyou.php) without showing the form so the user can enter shipping info.  Also, with the logic that the author used, I don't see how the shipping info is ever going to get to the next page since there is a header statement before it.  And lastly, I don't see any logic to process the Submit Order or Cancel order.

I am a noob at PHP, but learning fast;  I have been programming for a long, long time and this just doesn't make any sense.  Could someone please tell me:

- why is the page not being displayed
- is the logic farkeled as I suspect?  and if so, what would be the best way to fix it?
- how are the two buttons supposed to work?  (these are the settings for the Submit Order button)

[image]

Comment: You didn't post any HTML markup… Also, don't trust user input: the fact that you have a POST request, doesn't mean you have all those `$_POST` variables. Also, `"."` doesn't make any sense, please get rid of those.

Comment: Oh my …, lots of CSS in your markup, please get rid of that and use a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Also, the shipping info is transferred to session variables and then thankyou.php is loaded. That file probably processes the info, though that's not a good design.

Comment: I don't have a choice on how it's generated; I'm using an app called Quick n' Easy Web Builder... Concrete5 was too expensive for eCommerce ($125) and the customer balked at the price.

Comment: Huh? Your HTML and PHP are not in the same file? You can control the PHP and not the HTML? I'm really confused, now.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel what I see is the shipping info is loaded AFTER the thankyou.php is loaded.

Comment: No, they're copied in other variables, nothing more, nothing less…

Comment: The shipping info gets to the next page because it's put into session variables. These variables are carried between pages.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the form wouldn't be displayed. How do you go to the page the first time? Are you following a link, or submitting another form?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to go about this would be to use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitOrder']))
```

Instead of this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

The "Submit Order" button will only be set if it is the one that is click.

Comment: While this should work, why won't the original method work? The request method should only be `POST` when the form is submitted.